# Edit interfaces file in C++

Tags: networking, interface

Is there any known API to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` file?

I've written a piece of code to make the user able to change IP address of the system from the frontend (web interface). I'm modifying the interfaces file with std::ostream. It works but the code is a little messy.

Would be great if there is a standard way of doing this.

Comment: Might be relevant (also is 4+ years old) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627063/parsing-etc-network-interfaces

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but it was a little bit complex to handle that basic file. Wonder why this cannot be managed with Linux internals.

Comment: This is not standard to Linux; this is done differently by different distributions.  `/etc/network/interfaces` is from Debian-based distros. Redhat/Fedora/RHEL/CentOS use files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`.  Slackware uses `rc.inet1` and `rc.inet2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the wanted answer, but depending on how good you are with regular expressions, you should not neglect reading the whole file in, and doing a pattern find and substitute. I presume C++ provides an adequate regex library.

One advantage is that you can develop and test the regex outside your application, for example at this regex testing [website](https://regex101.com/r/lkLRaO/1) where I have put a simple file, pattern, and substitution you can play with.

Of course, a regex might be more difficult to read than the C++ code that you already have, but it is a very powerful language, and can be made more readable by using a version that allows inline comments, or by building it up from several string parts.

Comment: Great idea, I'll give it a try. However I still wonder if there is a standard way of doing this.

Comment: If you are looking to not reinvent the wheel, you might be able to extract the `uci` utility from [openwrt](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/uci). OpenWRT generates a web interface from a set of simple config files, and updates files like `/etc/network/interfaces` from the web by converting the requests to simple `uci` commands. It's not C++, but if you are planning to make other web GUI interfaces it might be worth investigating.